# EPSG:3035 WMS layer over Google Maps or OSM

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, wms, google-maps

Is it possible to put EPSG:3035 WMS layer over Google Maps or OSM?
I managed to do this, but my WMS layer is placed differently then Google Maps or OSM. I assume, Google Maps/OSM uses different projection.

I was wondering is it possible to show my EPSG:3035 WMS layer over "map" (without transforming my WMS data)?

I managed to put my WMS layer in correct position, but then WMS layer "gets" curved and OpenLayers fills rest of the square black - which is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  You will either have to find a suitable (matching projection) base map, or reproject your data to match the Google basemap projection (variant of Mercator).  Your WMS server *should* be able to do it.

However, if your layers match up "close enough" within some bounding area (few streets, or most of the city) then you should consider constraining your map bounds to that bounding box, and those zoom levels where the two layers match up.  Then the user won't be able to see bad or un-matched areas.

Comment: I'm using GeoServer with geotiff datastore. I want to put "Corine Land Cover 2000 raster data" over some "real" map.

Comment: If i change geotiff projection it loses most of its resolution.

Comment: Reprojection of itself does not lose resolution, @Artis: look for some way to control the output resolution in your reprojection software and try again.